# how to copy data from grid to mysql database in php

Tags: javascript, php, gridview

How to copy data from grid to mysql database using php?

I have about 1000 records from a local DB and i have to display these on a page ,then transfer them to a live dB.....thought of using grid cause in asp.net you can copy grid values to db any similar methods in PHp...OR any other possible way to do

insert has to be done based on multiple selection(only selected values must be inserted)

Db structure

1. Name varchar
2. List item
3. Date recieved Date
4. Address varchar
5. Hours worked varchar
6. Idle time varchar
7. Date completed date

Comment: Can't you just export the local DB to a CSV file and import it into mysql?

Comment: like i told ,have to display it in a page before uploading

Comment: Print them to a webpage and then execute an insert query?

Comment: I would probably put them in a DataTable and then insert them to mysql. Easy solution on top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

the below  link  tells   how to add the data  gathered from the db into  jQuery Grid and display it on a webpage
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/317145/Bind-jQuery-Grid-to-MySql-Database-using-PHP